# Unregular work of FTP

Tags: ftp, nao-robot

I connect to a NAO robot using ftp to read a photo from its memory. Here is my code:

```
def getPhoto():
    ftp = FTP("169.254.87.118")
    ftp.login("nao", "nao")
    ftp.cwd("recordings/cameras")

    local_filename = os.path.join(r"pictures", "newnao.jpg")
    lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + "image.jpg", lf.write)
```

The problem with this is sometimes it works correctly, sometimes it doesn't. I run the script, and it downloads from the robot not the new picture that I have just taken but the old - the same that was downloaded the last time. I run the script again and it downloads the correct picture.
I checked the robot's memory with filezilla - it has the correct picture. But somehow through ftp i get the wrong one. 
Any ideas on how this could be fixed? Many thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 0):

a silly answer: delete it after each download...